# Dynamic meta tags in Angular 1.5.9 from API service

Tags: angularjs, facebook, angular-ui-router, meta-tags

I have a portal built in Angular 1.5.9 with ui-router used. Now, when the user clicks on something and the route changes, the meta tags are supposed to change. Or when the user shares the link to Facebook, it's meta information should show up.

For example when user comes to /home, default meta tags will show up. 
when the route changes to /detail, information from an API service will populate meta tags. Hence when the url is shared on other sites - the meta tags should come from the service.

*Note: there is a hash in the url.*

**What I've tried**

1. using prerender.io - did not work as it is paid and does not completely suit my issue.
2. tried redirecting facebook bot to a file named meta.php that will get the meta tags but I need to know the URL that the facebook bot is trying to access, based on that I will load the API information into the tags. 
   Problem in this point (no. 2) is that I am unable to get the complete URL that the Facebook bot is accessing. After the hash (#) in the URL, the server (nginx) is unable to recognize the full URL which I am trying to get as a parameter. So, if a user shares url website.com/#/page/details/23, I'm only getting website.com/# so it loads the default meta tags and not the specific ones.
3. created a service "metaService" to get meta Atags but they do not show up in Facebook debugger as it loads afterwards. Calling the metaService in onEnter inside the state but doesn't work.

What I already know

- I'm using a very old version of Angular as the project is old and can't be upgraded.
- Angular is preferably for SPAs and this is not an SPA.

Comment: The hash portion of a URL is a merely client-side construct, and not even send to the server. So you won’t be able to get access to that on the server side to begin with.

Comment: But when a url say website.com/#/page/details/2 is shared, I want to be able to get the information for page detail with ID 2 via an API that I'll run but I need the full URL that is being accessed by the Facebook bot to get meta info. I will pass this url as a parameter to website.com/meta.php?(url) and will know what to do next.

Comment: You can “want” all you want, doesn’t change the fact that it is not technically possible to begin with. Your server-side logic will only ever get to see a request for `website.com/`, the `#/page/details/2` part never gets there. If you are in control of “how” users will share (say by providing them with Share buttons), then you can put your own “replacement” URL directly in there, something like `website.com/meta.php?page=details/2`,

Comment: so that you get the necessary info on the server side. But if users copy&paste the `website.com/#/page/details/2` they see in the address bar, or use any other way of triggering this that passes _this_ URL on directly to Facebook - nope …